# Why does dereferencing pointer from mmap cause memory usage reported by top to increase?

Tags: linux, mmap

I am calling mmap() with MAP_SHARED and PROT_READ to access a file which is about 25 GB in size. I have noticed that advancing the returned pointer has no effect to %MEM in top for the application, but once I start dereferencing the pointer at different locations, memory wildly increases and caps at 55%. That value goes back down to 0.2% once munmap is called.

I don't know if I should trust that 55% value top reports. It doesn't seem like it is actually using 8 GB of the available 16. Should I be worried?

Comment: The system doesn't actually allocate the memory until it is used. That's why, by using it, you cause it to be reserved.

Comment: From what I understand, I should only be using virtual address space without pages allocated. It makes me wonder if my application is reporting that it is using some set of virtual addresses once the pointer is dereferenced, but no physical memory is actually being used. That would make the 55% reported by top not mean much.

Comment: `%MEM` shows the resident set. That is, how much actual memory the program is currently using. But that's only part of the story: if that memory is shared, it will show as resident for all processes sharing it. On the other hand, in the case of a file mapping, the system may recover that memory anytime if it needs to so, though your program is using it, it's not blocking it from other programs.

Comment: It would seem like you are correct. I used another utility which helps me see what is reclaimable in memory and what isn't. It's mostly reclaimable in this case. If you put that as the answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first map the file, all it does is reserve address space, it doesn't necessarily read anything from the file if you don't pass `MAP_POPULATE` (the OS might do a little prefetch, it's not required to, and often doesn't until you begin reading/writing).

When you read from a given page of memory for the first time, this triggers a [page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault). This "invalid page fault" most people think of when they hear the name, it's either:

1. A minor fault - The data is already loaded in the kernel, but the userspace mapping for that address to the loaded data needs to be established (fast)
2. A major fault - The data is not loaded at all, and the kernel needs to allocate a page for the data, populate it from the disk (slow), then perform the same mapping to userspace as in the minor fault case

The behavior you're seeing is likely due to the mapped file being too large to fit in memory alongside everything else that wants to stay resident, so:

1. When first mapped, the initial pages aren't already mapped to the process (some of them might be in the kernel cache, but they're not charged to the process unless they're linked to the process's address space by minor page faults)
2. You read from the file, causing minor and major faults until you fill main RAM
3. Once you fill main RAM, faulting in a new page typically leads to one of the older pages being dropped (you're not using all the pages as much as the OS and other processes are using theirs, so the low activity pages, especially ones that can be dropped for free rather than written to the page/swap file, are ideal pages to discard), so your memory usage steadies (for every page read in, you drop another)
4. When you `munmap`, the accounting against your process is dropped. Many of the pages are likely still in the kernel cache, but unless they're remapped and accessed again soon, they're likely first on the chopping block to discard if something else requests memory

And as commenters noted, shared memory mapped file accounting gets *weird*; every process is "charged" for the memory, but they'll all report it as shared even if no other processes map it, so it's not practical to distinguish "shared because it's `MAP_SHARED` and backed by kernel cache, but no one else has it mapped so it's effectively uniquely owned by this process" from "shared because N processes are mapping the same data, reporting `shared_amount * N` usage cumulatively, but actually only consuming `shared_amount` memory total (plus a trivial amount to maintain the per-process page tables for each mapping). There's no reason to be worried if the tallies don't line up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This matches up very well with what I was noticing. The only thing I'm not clear on is what you mean by "main RAM". Are you distinguishing between physical RAM vs swap or is that referencing some other limit?

Comment: @Tails86: Yeah, I'm referring to actual physical RAM, as opposed to swap. The OS likes to keep everything in use in physical RAM, but obviously can't always do that, so file-backed memory mapped as shared that hasn't been dirtied can be dropped under pressure (written if it's dirty, reloaded if it's accessed again), and other memory can be written to the page/swap file (and reread on demand).